# Making a visible/invisible panel that resizes the main window

Tags: wpf, xaml, resize, panel, visibility

I wish to achieve an effect like common media players with an eq or tracklist panel that can be shown or less with a click.
The main window should so automatically resize with the displayed content.
I wonder if I must care to do manually specifing the size or there's a solution more clear.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplicationAnimation.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Margin="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">Value 1:</Label>
    <Label Margin="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">Value 2:</Label>
    <Label Margin="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2">Value 3:</Label>
    <Button Margin="5" Click="Button_Click_1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Visibility="Hidden">Hello</Button>
    <TextBox Name="txt1" Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" MinWidth="100" />
    <TextBox Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" MinWidth="100" />
    <TextBox Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" MinWidth="100" />        
</Grid>
```

I tried with setting SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" but even if visible the content of the button take the required space.

Comment: You should post what you've tried... or some code...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use an [Expander](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.expander.aspx) although will not be the same effect. The problem will be Window Transparency (so you can get a rid out of that, as Winamp does; but then you get into a [Memory Leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12167423/is-using-allowstransparency-property-on-a-wpf-window-still-a-cause-for-a-weird-m)). But, expander is the only control I know that enables to to that automatically. Sure, you can always arrange and resize manually, but that's what you're trying to avoid.